# pcapnet and packet redirection

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, ndis, kernel-mode

is it possible to mirror (not redirect/forward) packets on one ethernet interface to another?
The host machine will process the packets anyway, and since winpcap won't interpose as a filter, we wont be able to drop packets, I know. But I was wondering whether packet mirroring is possible using Winpcap or pcap.net?

Somewat similar to interface bridge.
Using a custom NDIS 5/6 filter driver is an option, but not pursuing now. I'm trying to do this in strictly usermode, and would be happy if I could use C#.

Using Win7x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. You can achieve the same using the WinPcap. There is a project out there, daemonlogger which uses the libpcap, port it to windows. To use C#, trying Pcap.net